# Get rules Entry time and exit time in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to identify the entry and exit time of the data. The calculation of exit time is, If the rule is not in the next activity, then that is the exit time for that rule.

here is how my data looks like.

```
     DECLARE @T AS TABLE
    (
                Visit_ID    INT,
                Line        INT,
                Rule_ID     INT,
                Activity_DTTM datetime
    )
        

insert into @T VALUES

(123, 1, 100072, '2022-07-01 03:05:00.000' ),
(123, 1, 100173, '2022-07-01 03:05:00.000' ),
(123, 1, 718719, '2022-07-01 03:05:00.000' ),
(123, 2, 100072, '2022-07-01 04:05:00.000' ),
(123, 2, 718719, '2022-07-01 04:05:00.000' ),
(123, 3, 100072, '2022-07-01 06:00:00.000' ),
(123, 4, 100072, '2022-07-02 02:10:00.000' ),
(123, 4, 100173, '2022-07-02 02:10:00.000' )


DECLARE @Desiredresult AS TABLE
(
    Visit   INT,
    Rule_ID INT,
    Entry_Time datetime,
    Exit_Time datetime

)

insert into @Desiredresult VALUES

(123,100072,'2022-07-01 03:05:00.000', null ),
(123,100173,'2022-07-01 03:05:00.000', '2022-07-01 04:05:00.000'),
(123,718719,'2022-07-01 03:05:00.000', '2022-07-01 06:00:00.000'),
(123,100173,'2022-07-02 02:10:00.000', null)


select * from @Desiredresult
```

Is this a version of Gaps and Islands problem?  I have written a SQL and it was very inefficient where it's taking more than 2hrs. to process 10 million rows.

This is the query i tried.

```
select me.Visit_ID
,me.Rule_ID
, MIN(CASE WHEN prev_split.line is null then me.ACTIVITY_DTTM else null end) as ENTRY_DTTM
, MAX(CASE WHEN next_split.line is null
        then next_flat.Activity_DTTM                
        else null end
        ) as EXIT_DTTM

from @T me
left join @T prev_flat on me.Visit_ID = prev_flat.Visit_ID and me.LINE-1 = prev_flat.line -- minus 1    
left join @T next_flat on me.Visit_ID = next_flat.Visit_ID and me.LINE+1 = prev_flat.line -- plus 1

left join @T prev_split on me.Visit_ID = prev_split.Visit_ID  and me.RULE_ID = prev_split.RULE_ID and me.LINE-1 = prev_split.line -- minus 1
left join @T next_split on me.Visit_ID = next_split.Visit_ID  and me.RULE_ID = next_split.RULE_ID and me.LINE+1 = next_split.line -- plus 1

group by me.Visit_ID
,me.Rule_ID
```

Comment: Please include your existing query and the desired results for the sample data.

Comment: I have added the query i tried to the original question and created the desired result temp table.

Comment: I don't understand the logic: why does row 2 of the desired results have an ExitDate? Please show the steps of your calculation

Comment: Because in line 3 (from row 6) the 2nd row rule was not there, hence that’s the exit time for that rule.