# Having issue in determining the correct Entry time and Exit time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to identify the entry and exit time of the data. The calculation of exit time is, If the activity is not in the next activity line, then that is the exit time for that activity.

Can someone please help me to fix the below SQL.

Example: Here is the sample data

```
| VisitID | Line | ActivityName |   ActivityTime    |
-----------------------------------------------------
|   123   |  1   |   Activity1  |'2022-07-01 03:00' |
|   123   |  1   |   Activity2  |'2022-07-01 03:00' |
|   123   |  1   |   Activity3  |'2022-07-01 03:00' |
|   123   |  2   |   Activity1  |'2022-07-01 04:10' |
|   123   |  2   |   Activity2  |'2022-07-01 04:10' |
|   123   |  2   |   Activity3  |'2022-07-01 04:10' |
|   123   |  3   |   Activity1  |'2022-07-02 07:00' |
|   123   |  3   |   Activity3  |'2022-07-02 07:00' |
|   123   |  4   |   Activity1  |'2022-07-03 09:00' |
|   123   |  5   |   Activity2  |'2022-07-04 05:00' |
```

Here is how the output should be

```
| VisitID | ActivityName |     StartTime     |      EndTime     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   123   |  Activity1  |'2022-07-01 03:00' |'2022-07-04 05:00' |
|   123   |  Activity2  |'2022-07-01 03:00' |'2022-07-02 07:00' |
|   123   |  Activity3  |'2022-07-01 03:00' |'2022-07-03 09:00' |
|   123   |  Activity2  |'2022-07-04 05:00' |'2022-07-04 05:00' |
```

Sample SQL Table

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
            VisitID    INT,
            Line        INT,
            ActivityName Nvarchar(25),
            ActivityTime datetime
)


insert into @T VALUES

(123, 1, 'Activity1', '2022-07-01 03:00' ),
(123, 1, 'Activity2', '2022-07-01 03:00' ),
(123, 1, 'Activity3', '2022-07-01 03:00' ),
(123, 2, 'Activity1', '2022-07-01 04:10' ),
(123, 2, 'Activity2', '2022-07-01 04:10' ),
(123, 2, 'Activity3', '2022-07-01 04:10' ),
(123, 3, 'Activity1', '2022-07-02 07:00' ),
(123, 3, 'Activity3', '2022-07-02 07:00' ),
(123, 4, 'Activity1', '2022-07-03 09:00' ),
(123, 5, 'Activity2', '2022-07-04 05:00' )
```

SQL I have so far:

```
select tmp.ActivityName
    ,[Entry date] = min(tmp.ActivityTime)
    ,[Exit date] = max(tmp.ActivityTime)
from
(
    select t.ActivityName , t.ActivityTime
        , [Dense Rank] = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ActivityName  ORDER BY t.ActivityTime)
        , [Group] = DATEADD(DAY,-1 * DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ActivityName  ORDER BY t.ActivityTime) ,t.ActivityTime)    
    from @T t
) tmp    
group by tmp.ActivityName,  tmp.[Group]
```

Comment: In what way is [Get rules Entry time and exit time in a row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72893393/92546) related? The algorithm employed isn't any better defined in this question, nor is the importance of `VisitID`.

Comment: This question has formatted sample data, and a script that includes DDL and sample data population. It has an attempt, provided as formatted code. Yes, part of the puzzle here was determining exactly what was needed, but that just takes a couple of passes through the sample data and results, so that's no different from what programmers do every day. To me it's 100% clear that the OP just can't figure out the query required. And fair enough too, it's not trivial. Upvote from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the value of `ActivityTime` is functionally dependent upon the value of `Line`, I believe the following query gets you what you want.

I have made no attempt to optimize the logic for performance. It is a "direct" translation of the requirement logic into SQL.

How it works:

For each row in the original rowset, it finds, in order of `line` ascending, the first row in the set of rows which have a higher `line` than the original row's `line`, but the original row's `activityName` does not exist in the set. I alias this set as `nxt`, ie, "next".

However, this is not sufficent because a given `ActivityName` might start and end more than once. For example, "Activity2" is in the set where `line = 1`, then disappears once we reach `line = 4`, but reappears when `line = 5`.

Therefore I group the intermediate results by the value of `line` in the set we retrieved in step 1. I can also safely group by `nxt.ActivityTime`, because `nxt.ActivityTime` is functionally dependent upon `nxt.line` (it's not necessary to include `line`, here, but it makes it much easier to read the ungrouped output).

The starting time for the row is then just the minimum value of `ActivityTIme` from the original rows within this group.

Finally, if there is no "following set" (such as is the case with "Activity2" on line 5), I infer from your expected results that you want the `EndTime` to just be the same as the `StartTime`. This is what the `isnull` is for.

To understand it better I suggest running the query without the `group by` or `min` to see the intermediate results.

```sql
select         t.VisitId,
               t.ActivityName,
               StartTime = min(t.ActivityTime),
               EndTime = isnull(nxt.ActivityTime, min(t.ActivityTime))
from           @t t
outer apply    (
                  select   top 1 line, activityTime
                  from     @t t2
                  where    t2.visitId = t.visitId
                           and t2.line > t.line
                           and not exists
                           (
                              select *
                              from   @t t3
                              where  t3.activityName = t.activityName
                                     and t3.visitId = t2.visitId
                                     and t3.line = t2.line
                           )
                  order by t2.line asc
               ) nxt
group by       t.VisitId,
               t.ActivityName,
               nxt.line,
               nxt.ActivityTime
order by       min(t.ActivityTime);
```